# Alert in Javascript does not work properly

Tags: javascript, c#, focus, alert

I am creating a custom control in Asp.net and there is a client side validation on an input field.

Control Code (extract of the whole code):

```
output.AddAttribute("OnBlur", "ValidateText(this)");
output.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Input);
```

And here is the JS code:

```
function ValidateText(ctl) {
    if (ctl.value == '') {
        alert("Enter something!");
        ctl.focus();
    }
}
```

I want the function to show an alert and then make the input field focused.

However, when I run the code, the alert box does not go away after a click or pressing the Enter key and I need to do it couple of times.

What is wrong in the code?

Comment: sounds like an issue with your browser.

Comment: you are correct. It did not work in Chrome but works perfectly in Edge. Any suggestion to make it work in Chrome as well?

Comment: try it in incognito mode and see if it is some extension causing you issues

Answer (score -1):

```
function ValidateText(ctl) {
  if (ctl === '' || ctl === undefined) {
      alert("Enter something!");
      ctl.focus();
  }
}
```

Comment: `this` is an input. It is passed to `ValidateText`. How is an input equal to an empty string ever going to be true. This is incorrect.